# SQLAlchemy column-properties and relationships return booleans

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Consider the two data models:

```
Child(id, parent_id) :: ForeignKey on Child.parent_id => Parent.id
Parent(id, children) :: children = relationship(Child.parent_id == id)
```

The following SQLAlchemy query:

```
session.query(Parent.children).limit(1).all()
```

yields:

```
[[False]]
```

The result is not correct because the relationship queries are not being executed for each returned column of the rows. I was expecting an output akin to the following:

```
[[{id:5, parent_id:8}]]
```

**NOTE** When I fetch the entire Parent object via. `get`, the `children` attribute query is executed correctly as such

```
session.query(Parent).get(8)

# output
# { id: 8, children: [{id:5, parent_id:8}] }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a look at the generated SQL, we see that

```
>>> print str(s.query(Parent.children))
SELECT parent.id = child.parent_id AS children 
FROM parent, child
```

Since you put a limit and we have a cartesian join, your first result is False (as parent.id may not equal child.parent_id for first parent and child).

The reason AFAIK is that `Parent.children` is not a traditional column but a [RelationshipProperty](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/internals.html?highlight=columnproperty#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty) and hence behaves differently.

Assuming you want to get all the Child elements corresponding to a parent, you can do as you have shown in the second part of your question

```
>>> par=session.query(Parent).filter_by(id=someid).first()
>>> par.children
```

Here `par.children` will be evaluated as per your relationship configuration (See [Relationship Loading Techniques](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html) in the manual) and hence "join" SQL may be emitted only for the second expression (if you have lazy loading relationship)

Another option is to explicilty join and only fetch the Child

```
>>> s.query(Parent).join(Parent.children).with_entities(Child).filter(Parent.id==1).all()
[<__main__.Child object at 0x145b950>, <__main__.Child object at 0x145ba50>]
```

Comment: consider a case where the parent has numerous columns and relationships. what is the most efficient way to perform a select on only several of the columns given that we don't know if the selected columns are relationship attributes or regular sql attributes.

Comment: An additional case is if we only want to select several columns statically defined. What is the best way to perform that.

Comment: "select" can only be used on columns. When you say you want to select some relationships, I assume you want to select columns in the remote table associated with those relationships. In that case, the query given at the end of your question is the best bet