# SQLAlchemy querying for Parent's multiple Children returns [(bool, bool)]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following `SQLAlchemy` data model:

```
class Parent:
    @declared_attr
    def child_A_id(cls):
        return Column(ForeignKey(Child.id), nullable=True)

    @declared_attr
    def child_B_id(cls):
        return Column(ForeignKey(Unit.id), nullable=True)

    @declared_attr
    def child_A(cls):
        return relationship(Child, primaryjoin=lambda: cls.child_A_id == Child.id)

    @declared_attr
    def child_B(cls):
        return relationship(Child, primaryjoin=lambda: cls.child_A_id == Child.id)
```

I am trying to query for both the `child_A` and `child_B` object using the following query:

```
session.query(Parent.child_A, Parent.child_B).limit(1).all()
```

which just returns a bool instead of an object (e.g. `[(False, False)]` instead of `[{child_A_columns}, {child_B_columns}]`.

I looked at [SQLAlchemy column-properties and relationships return booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428411/sqlalchemy-column-properties-and-relationships-return-booleans) which solves this problem for one `child` but can't figure out how to apply it for this case where one `Parent` has two `child` relationships to the same table.

---

Attempted solutions:

```
parent = session.query(Parent).limit(1).all()
parent.child_A
parent.child_B
```

Works but requires a `SELECT *` which I am trying to avoid.

```
session.query(Parent.child_A, Parent.child_B).with_entity(Child).limit(1).all()
```

only returns one `Child`.

Comment: Do you want to avoid querying `Parent` at the same time, or is eager loading an ok solution?

Comment: I'm okay with that; could you explain how you would use eager loading here?

Comment: @IljaEverilä A question on SQLAlchemy Relationships that I am looking for answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71266107/sqlalchemy-relationships-row-in-child-table-is-dependent-on-two-parent-tables

Answer (score 0):

The [question and answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428411/sqlalchemy-column-properties-and-relationships-return-booleans) explain why the query results in a 2-tuple of booleans, but in order to query for both children that – according to description – originate from the same table you need [aliases](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-aliases):

```
child_a = aliased(Child)
child_b = aliased(Child)

session.query(child_a, child_b).\
    select_from(Parent).\
    join(child_a, Parent.child_A).\
    join(child_b, Parent.child_B)
```

If you wish to use [`Query.with_entities()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities), you still have to prepare the joins first:

```
session.query(Parent).\
    join(child_a, Parent.child_A).\
    join(child_b, Parent.child_B).\
    with_entities(child_a, child_b)
```

On the other hand you could load parents with their children in a single query:

```
session.query(Parent).\
    options(joinedload(Parent.child_A),
            joinedload(Parent.child_B))
```